# Shell scripts using Cron can't execute shell commands

Tags: cron, openshift

I'm trying to restart my server with cron. I've found this link:

https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202187644-Shell-scripts-using-Cron-or-action-hooks-can-t-execute-shell-commands

But does not work. This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /usr/bin/rhcsh
ctl_all restart
```

And this the output:

```
/usr/bin/rhcsh: line 7: source: filename argument required
source: usage: source filename [arguments]
/usr/bin/rhcsh: line 32: build_path: command not found
/usr/bin/rhcsh: line 33: build_ld_library_path: No such file or directory
    *********************************************************************
    You are accessing a service that is for use only by authorized users.
    If you do not have authorization, discontinue use at once.
    Any use of the services is subject to the applicable terms of the
    agreement which can be found at:
    https://www.openshift.com/legal
    *********************************************************************
    Welcome to OpenShift shell
    This shell will assist you in managing OpenShift applications.
    !!! IMPORTANT !!! IMPORTANT !!! IMPORTANT !!!
    Shell access is quite powerful and it is possible for you to
    accidentally damage your application.  Proceed with care!
    If worse comes to worst, destroy your application with "rhc app delete"
    and recreate it
    !!! IMPORTANT !!! IMPORTANT !!! IMPORTANT !!!
    Type "help" for more info.
Command "quota" not found for app xxxxx, please check the node hosting this app
WARNING: This ssh terminal was started without a tty.
          It is highly recommended to login with: ssh -t
Restarting services
/usr/bin/rhcsh: line 123: gear: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?

Many thanks.

Edit:

Here is rhcsh script (The script has 300 lines, so I've uploaded to a server):

http://www6.zippyshare.com/v/99209351/file.html

Comment: Seems that something is wrong in your /usr/bin/rhcsh file. Can you paste its content?

Comment: Hi Tomasz, the problem is that cron is mounted on OpenShift (https://www.openshift.com) infrastructure and the script can not be modified. If you still want to see the script can add it to the main post.

Comment: Still might be helpful. The problem probably is not in the script itself, but in something it utilizes, maybe some environment variable. I am particularily curious what is at line 7 where the first error occurred.

Comment: I agree with Tomasz having the script will be helpful.

Comment: I've added file a link.

Comment: As I suspected, the problem is with unset environment variables. Try to add "source ~/.bash_profile" or "source ~/.profile" before sourcing /usr/bin/rhcsh.

Comment: Dosen't works :/ .profile is in app-root/data/.bash_profile, I've tried source /var/lib/openshift/538e3e4c5973ca3f4600012e/app-root/data/.bash_profile and source ~/app-root/data/.bash_profile. This second option is in rchsc script, line 3
Thanks Tomasz

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
gear restart --all-cartridges    # same as: ctl_all restart
```

`ctl_all` is a wrapper function for `/usr/bin/gear` script.